# Test empty method body with Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

As the title suggests, is there any way to see if a method has an empty body using reflection?

Comment: *No* , as far as I know , can you please tell me why you want to check this ? interesting requirement

Answer (score 4):

With reflection, I don't think so. You could look into [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) though...

> The Byte Code Engineering Library is
>   intended to give users a **convenient
>   possibility to analyze**, create, and
>   manipulate (binary) Java class files

Here is a snip that might get you started from this [article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/10/22/bcel.html?page=3)...

```
public class ClassViewer{
   private JavaClass clazz;
   public ClassViewer(String clazz){
      this.clazz = Repository.lookupClass(clazz);
    }
   public static void main(String args[]){
      if(args.length != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "One and only one class at a time!");
      ClassViewer viewer = new ClassViewer(args[0]);
      viewer.start();
    }
   private void start(){
      if(this.clazz != null){
        // first print the structure 
        // of the class file
        System.err.println(clazz);
        // next print the methods
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
       for(int i=0; i<methods.length; i++){
          System.err.println(methods[i]);
          // now print the actual
          // byte code for each method
          Code code = methods[i].getCode();
         if(code != null)
            System.err.println(code);
       }
     }else
        throw new RuntimeException(
          "Class file is null!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't inspect that actual (byte-)code of any given method using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of information isn't available via usual reflection API, which retrieves class and instance variables, method signatures, etc., but not actual bytecode.

You could use a library:

JavaAssist

- http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

BCEL

- http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use "Java agents". There shouldn't be any reasonable excuse to do this sort of thing. Having said that, typical implementations of the JVM itself will do this sort of thing to ignore finalizable objects.